# Json Formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, custom-list, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am in a position where all I want to do is change the font color of a column to `#002c77` no matter what the text within the text field says. I cannot for the life of me get it to work, and there I am sure I am doing something wrong.

until now I have it like this and it does not work

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if([$Stadie] == 'Stadie 1 - Påbegyndt', '#002c77',
    if([$Stadie] == 'Stadie 2 - Påbegyndt', '#002c77', 
    if([$Stadie] == 'Stadie 3 - Påbegyndt', '#002c77', 
    if([$Stadie] == 'Stadie 4 - Påbegyndt', '#002c77', 
    if([$Stadie] == 'Completed', '#002c77')))))"
  }    
}
```

And previously I tried this:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "@currentField", 
   "style":{
     "color":{
       "operator": "?",
       "operands": [
         {
           "operator": "==",
           "operands": [
             "@currentField", "Stadie 1 - Påbegyndt",
             {
               "operator": "==",
               "operands": [
                 "@currentField", "Stadie 2 - Påbegyndt"
               ]
             },
             "#002c77",
             ""
          ] 
         },
         "#002c77",
         ""
       ]
     }
   }
}
```

But it only seemed to work with the first one and not the ones after, anyone know how to format the text within a field no matter what it says so that the font color is changed to `#002c77`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the data type of your field/column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below JSON Code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "#002c77"
  }
}
```

**Official documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting).

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! :)